# ASP.NET MVC Razor で HTML を Minify する方法はありますか？

Tags: .net, asp.net, razor

VS2013 .NET Framework 4.5環境 ビュー・エンジンは「Razor」を利用しています。

PHPのSmartyでいうところの {strip} タグのような、不要なスペースや改行を取り除いた Minify された状態のHTMLを生成する簡単な方法はありますでしょうか？

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio の拡張機能 SideWaffle では WhitespaceModule という Minify するための HTTP モジュールが提供されています。

https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/blob/master/TemplatePack/ItemTemplates/Web/ASP.NET/WhitespaceModule/WhitespaceModule.cs

実装のメインは WhitespaceFilter クラスなので、ActionFilter で Response.Filter にセットする使い方も出来ます。

http://forums.asp.net/t/1380989.aspx

ただし、マルチバイト文字の扱いを考慮していないケースが多いので、その点だけ注意が必要ですね。

Answer (score 1):

使ったことは無いのですが興味があるので調べてみました。
WebMarkupMin.Mvcが良いのではないでしょうか。

- http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/WebMarkupMin.Core
- https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin

Answer (score 1):

Razorはインラインで書かれた特定の範囲のHTMLに対してのみ加工を行うような処理には向いていません。
{strip}のように部分的なminifyを強引にやるとすれば、

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString StripWhitespaces(this HtmlHelper self, Func<object, HelperResult> template)
{
    // 一番単純なminifyの例です。
    return new MvcHtmlString(template(self.ViewData.Model).ToString()
        .Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("\t", ""));
}
```

このような拡張メソッドを用意して、以下のように使うくらいでしょうか。

```html
@Html.StripWhitespaces(@<text>
    <h1>
        hogehoge
    </h1>
</text>)
```

出力全体をminifyしたい場合は、お二方が仰るようにHttpModuleやActionFilterを使った方法しか無いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

要望はたまに上がるみたいですが、公式にはまだのようですね。

aspnet/Mvc issues

- [MVC RenderSection with Minification](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/571)
- [Minify Razor Output](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1110)

close になっていますが、対応しないのではなくて課題ではなく新機能として討論しようということの様です。

私も利用した事は無いですが、既に上がっている WebMarkupMin.Mvc 以外でもいくつかあるようです。

WebMarkupMin.Mvcはaction filterを利用してHTMLかXHTMLを処理しているようですね。以下に挙げるものは少し動作が異なるようです。

- https://github.com/Chebur9tina/HtmlOptimizerMvc4
  こちらは実行時ではなくビルド時にrazor viewをminifyするようです。
  MVC4用です（他の人がMVC5用にしたものをbitbucketで見かけました）
- http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Meleze.Web (https://github.com/meleze/Meleze.Web)
  こちらはrazorをminifyするようです。ただしpartial viewがminifyされないとか、bodyしかminifyされないとか見かけましたので、全体はminifyされないかもしれません。